# How do I make a specific function in R to simulate a biological situation

Tags: r, function, math, modulo, agent

I would need to write a function to wombat movement relative to their starting point and their preferred burrow range (which is around 3-8 burrows around the initiated burrow)

To do this, I need to:

1. Shuffle burrows from 1 to 246 (there are 246 burrows)
2. Select the first proportion of the population to be initiated in randomised burrows
3. Assign a number of preferred burrows for a wombat (3-8 burrows)
4. For each wombat with a starting position, give sequential burrow ID to each side of its initial burrow. However, this is a condition that arose:

   - If odd, no problem (e.g. 24 and 5 burrows -> 22, 23, 24, 25, 26)
   - If even, do the same as odd and then add another number to the left or right (e.g. 24 and 4 burrows -> 22, 23, 24, 25)
5. Make the burrow range selection to be modular arithmetic so the ones that started at the end of 246 burrows, their preferred burrows can continue to burrow number 1 and so on.

How should I logically tackle this?

So the way that burrow arrangement is that they are arranged in a circular pattern (edges of their habitat). I thought I could do %% function to create a modulo function but I have no clue how to do number 4 and 5 and how to make everything into one function.

I figured out to step 3 out of 5 so far...

```
burrownum = (1:246) #set number of burrows

rand_burrownum = permute::shuffle(burrownum) #randomise the burrows

assignbur2wom = as.data.frame(rand_burrownum[1:24]) #assign wombats (per set proportion - 24 for 10%, 43 for 17.5%, 61 for 25%) to initial burrow 

wombatID = as.data.frame(1:24) #ID of each wombats - need to change the number of individuals

assignpref2wom = as.data.frame(sample(3:8, 24, replace = TRUE))#sample how many of burrows each wombat prefers - need to change number of individuals

wombatdat$WomID = wombatID

wombatdat$InitialBurrows = assignbur2wom

wombatdat$NumBPref = assignpref2wom
```

I would like to get a function that creates these conditions. I know it is pretty complex, let me know if there is anything else I can clarify!

Comment: thanks for your question. The question is very broad, and because of that I don't expect a complete answer anytime soon. there are a lot of ways to go about this, and some solution may not be what you are looking for. What are the specific point you get stuck, and what have you tried so far? Keep in mind that the community is here to help you with coding issues, but not to do the coding for you.

Comment: @MKBakker thanks mate. If anyone can suggest different functions I can potentially fiddle with in steps 4 and 5 I'd be happy to explore it out. I just have no idea what functions I can use for them. You can probably tell, I'm pretty new to writing r scripts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following function might help:

```
assign.burrows <- function(i,k,n = 246) {
  a <- floor(i - 1 - (k-1)/2)
  b <- floor(i - 1 + (k-1)/2)
  1 + (a:b) %% n
}
```

Typical runs:

```
> assign.burrows(24,5)
[1] 22 23 24 25 26
> assign.burrows(24,4)
[1] 22 23 24 25
> assign.burrows(246,4)
[1] 244 245 246   1
> assign.burrows(246,5)
[1] 244 245 246   1   2
> assign.burrows(2,5)
[1] 246   1   2   3   4
```

Note that using 1-based indexing of the burrow numbers makes things more complicated since it doesn't play well with modular arithmetic. With 0-based indexing (so that the burrow numbers go from 0 to 245) you could just use:

```
assign.burrows <- function(i,k,n = 246) {
  a <- floor(i - (k-1)/2)
  b <- floor(i + (k-1)/2)
  (a:b) %% n
}
```

On the other hand, 1-based indexing plays nicer with R data structures, so it might on balance be preferable to stick with R's 1-based indexing.

Comment: This is amazing! Thank you so much John. That's definitely something I can explore and play around with. I'm going to try my best and see what you did so that I can apply the techniques in the figure! Cheers!